# Angular CLI - why does <ng serve> bundle better than <ng build>?

Tags: angular, webpack, minify, angular-cli

Performing a number of Angular CLI commands in order to build the minified basic project:

```
ng new project
cd project
ng build --prod
```

... as a result, I get the generated `dist` folder with a number of bundles. The largest one is called `vendor.[hash].js` and it's size about `855kB`.

However, if I perform `ng serve --prod` instead:

```
ng new project
cd project
ng serve --prod
```

... I can see the loaded by `localhost:4200` vendor's bundle weight is about `300kB` using Chrome console.

Why is that happens? Is there a way to achieve the second result without `ng serve` but rather with `ng build`?

Comment: Great question if it's really so (I am going to try it). Is it possible that ng serve holds something in memory or otherwise does not fully bundle all the assets, e.g. the webpack output for -prod will be different to make a fully deployable distribution set? I'm interested because when I use straight ES6 and webpack, and do a build, I tend to get MUCH less complicated distribution bundles that load faster. I've become semi-dubious of the CLI distribution outputs (probably due to some lack of knowledge around how to configure them exactly as I want via the cli config instead of webpack).

Comment: I tried it, it seems some assets might be getting cached.

Comment: @TimConsolazio, if to use webpack explicitly as it described at [Angular doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) the output will be very similar to `ng build --prod` one. Just have noticed the `cmd` outputs are a bit different, the `ng serve` output looks a bit large than other one

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking at the gzipped size in the console, and the not gzipped size of the generated file?

Comment: @JBNizet, indeed it is, now it's clear what happens there. Thank you:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was discovered through the comments, you simply compared two different values: the size of the non-gzipped file in the file system, and the size of the gzipped download in the browser console.

Answer (score 4):

It's not about which one is better.

It's all about when to use **build** or **serve**.

1. **build** is used for deployment purpose and **serve** is used for development purpose.
2. **build** generates compiled output to /dist directory and **serve** build artifacts from memory for a faster development experience.

Ref : [build vs. serve](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#build-vs-serve)

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in my environment:

ng build --prod = main.[hash].js = 792KB.

bg serve --prod = main.[hash].js = 863KB.

```
$ ng --version
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.19-3
node: 7.0.0
os: win32 x64
```

ng serve generate a cache file slightly smaller, because is temporary.

Update your ng cli and test again.

Comment: Have updated all the tools. Npm is `4.0.5`, node `7.3.0`, angular-cli `1.0.0-beta.24`. But everything is still the same. The weight difference seems become huge as soon as the app grown, just have installed Material 2 to the basic project. The weight difference is more than 1MB now, `280kB` vs `1300kB` one

Comment: Despite it's temporary, everything does work with this like it isn't. So weird