# Angular2 Too much loading time for bundle.js production

Tags: angular, production

I am using angular2 for my project.

I have used this command to generate build.

```
ng build --prod
```

Bundle.js size is 1.4MB.
In my application I am using angular2-google-maps, bootstrap, dropzone.

Is there any solution to fast my production site?

Comment: 1.4MB is really large for a js file though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular CLI - why does <ng serve> bundle better than <ng build>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407834/angular-cli-why-does-ng-serve-bundle-better-than-ng-build)

Comment: your server shall to have gzip compression enabled

Comment: You can also try to use the ahead of time compilation flag, `--aot`, to reduce the size even more (if you are using `angular-cli`)

Comment: Yes @john I have try with --aot option. But I am using angular2-google-map. But angular2-google-map not supporting --aot option.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this [link](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/),
Not worked on it but seems they are able to reduce size of bundle from 1.4Mb to 47K!.